# The parameterized query is not recognizing parameter in EF5?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I am trying to execute a stored procedure from EF5 using `Database.SqlQuery`. But 2nd parameter is not recognizing here.

> Error: "The parameterized query '(@custNum nvarchar(7), @PrimaryDisc bigint, @SecondaryDisc bigint)' expects the parameter '@PrimaryDisc', which was not supplied."

Code

```
var results = _MiscContext.Database.SqlQuery<TempTechDisciplines>(
        "exec sp_getTechnicalDiscipline @CustNum, @PrimaryDisc, @SecondaryDisc", 
        new SqlParameter("custNum", CustomerNum), 
        new SqlParameter("PrimaryDisc",SqlDbType.BigInt, 0), 
        new SqlParameter("SecondaryDisc",SqlDbType.BigInt, 0))
        .ToList<TempTechDisciplines>();
```

What is the issue here?

Comment: Try `@` while adding parameter names like : `new SqlParameter("@custNum", CustomerNum), `

Comment: did not work. by adding `@`

Comment: [I don't think you're using the SqlParameter constructor you think you are](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hex23w80(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Could casing be an issue? The query itself uses `CustNum`, but the parameter is named `custNum`.

Comment: Never used the biginteger types, but I'd try `new SqlParameter("@PrimaryDisc", new BigInteger(0))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me from this article.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/diego/archive/2012/01/10/how-to-execute-stored-procedures-sqlquery-in-the-dbcontext-api.aspx

```
var custNum = new SqlParameter {ParameterName = "CustNum", Value = CustomerNum};
var primaryDisc = new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "PrimaryDisc", Value = 0 };
var secondaryDisc = new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "SecondaryDisc", Value = 0 };

var results = _MiscContext.Database.SqlQuery<TempTechDisciplines>(
             "exec sp_getTechnicalDiscipline @CustNum, @PrimaryDisc,
              @SecondaryDisc",
              custNum,primaryDisc,secondaryDisc).ToList<TempTechDisciplines>();
```

Comment: Yes, setting the actual value should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

If a parameter value (`CustomerNum`) is null, the parameter will not be serialized, and this error will occur.

Check and add default values for **each** parameter you add (`'0' for CustomerNum`), and check if `CustomerNum <> 0` instead `IS NULL` if needed.